# Is there any Phonegap Plugin to Get Wifi Signal Strength and SSID for indoor navigation?

Tags: cordova, navigation, gps, mapping, wifi

I want to implement the indoor navigation in my Cordova(Phonegap) application for iOS and Android. As we know GPS should not available in indoors. I want to get the user's current location. So I am planning to calculate the current location using Wifi Signal Strength and SSID of Wifi routers. How can I fetch this parameters? is there any plugin for that? Even if I implement it, is the application may be rejected by Apple to publish in appstore(due to security reasons  since it accessing this Wifi details).

If it is not possible is there any other solutions to get the user's current location?

Please help me...

Comment: Have you considered using beacons? For example, with Estimote: https://github.com/evothings/phonegap-estimotebeacons or with Indoo.rs: https://github.com/nomos-system/cordova-indoors

Comment: Yes. But those need external hardwares.

Comment: This post is kinda of old, you might have very well stumbled on this one but still sharing it, hoping it helps. https://www.indooratlas.com/ its hardware independent Indoor Positioning System